# Numpy.where with logic

Tags: python, numpy

```
000000000
000050000
000505000
005000500
050000050
500040005
050000050
005000500
```

In this example, I want to find the index of the 5s which are in the same row as the 4. I already have the index of the 4 saved as `centre`.

The desired output is `[[5,0],[5,8]]`.

I attempted this but it doesn't work:

```
index = zip(*np.where(array== 5 and x == centre[0]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing index = zip(*np.where(array[centre[0],:] == 5))

Answer (score 0):

Solution with list comprehension:

```
arr = ['000000000',
       '000050000',
       '000505000',
       '005000500',
       '050000050',
       '500040005',
       '050000050',
       '005000500']

indices = [[j, i] 
           for j, row in enumerate(arr)
           for i, val in enumerate(row) 
           if '4' in row and val=='5']

print(indices)
# [[5, 0], [5, 8]]
```